# Is there a way to automatically discover an SQL database on your network?

Tags: java, mysql, networking

I am setting up a MySQL database at my work and am also building an interface so people can interact with it.

The company already has a server that they use to host shared files and this will be used to run the database. I would like to know if it would be safe to hardcode the IP address of the server as it will be turned off and on in the evening and mornings.

If the IP is likely to change then is there a way I could find the IP address of the server automatically in the program, without the user having to do anything extra manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can use DNS and connect on and FQDN.

You can use a network scanner (for instance nmap) to search for open port 3306

Comment: I  can already use a port sniffer or some such thing to find the open server, I was wondering if I could do this automatically inside the java application.

Comment: Write an TCP ip scanner in java, just a simple connect to tcp port 3306 with a short timeout.  for every IP address in your subnet.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have managed to do that and avoid the unreliability of pinging with sending a dummy SQL query (SELECT 1 AS A) to each IP, and check the response.